# Understanding the at-command to schedule another command

Tags: command-line, cron, scheduled, schedule, at-command

I use cron to schedule things in Linux, but recently I discovered the "at" command.

```
sudo apt-get install at
```

I don't understand the scope from which this command operates:

- How would you schedule a command with at, that normally requires
  admin privileges?
- What is the working directory (pwd) of a command scheduled with at?

Additionally, everything I've tried so far, didn't achieve what I was trying to do.

For example, I tried to launch gedit one minute from now:

```
echo "gedit" | at now + 1 minute
```

I waited a minute, and nothing happened.

I tried to turn off my monitor one minute from now:

```
echo "xset dpms force off" | at now + 1 minute
```

I waited a minute and nothing happened.

If I can't get "at" to reliably perform a task one minute from now, how can I be certain that it will perform something I tell it to do tomorrow and beyond?

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try instead:

```
~$  at now + 1 minute
at> ls -ahl > /tmp/at_test
at> ^D
```

You will find `/tmp/at_test` after command executed.

If you want to run some GUI app you should specify `DISPLAY` variable;
Use `echo $DISPLAY` to find out you display

```
~$  at now + 1 minute
at> DISPLAY=:0 gedit
at> ^D
```

Piping is also ok:

```
echo "DISPLAY=:0 gedit" | at now + 1 minute
```

Comment: Not working. I'm getting this error `warning: commands will be executed using /bin/sh` first then the `at>` prompt. Anything I type then doesn't run.

Comment: ^D means control+D, right? I tried this and the output was "job 5 at Mon Jun 16 11:54:00 2014". However, gedit never launched.

Comment: @dan08, `at` does not export `DISPLAY` variable.
@LonnieBest, you can run gedit using this: 
`at now + 1 minute`
`DISPLAY=:0 gedit`
`^D`

Comment: echo "DISPLAY=:0 gedit" | at now + 1 minute